# I uploaded my first program to ATmega328p and now i cannot upload anything

Tags: atmega

Ok guys, I wanted to make simple electronic device (mostly RGB display) so I bought all the stuff.

I have read like dozens of diffrent tutorials and I managed to connect ATmega328p to breadboard, I burned bootloader to it with my USBasp (internal 8Mhz clock). Everything seemed fine so I upload a Blink sketch from Arduino IDE. It worked great, the LED was powered from Pin13 (same as SCK from USBasp) and it was blinking. So I wanted to try Fading Sketch. But The Led kept blinking.

I was trying to upload ther sketches, empty sketches, burning bootloader, more sketches, more burning, diffrent bootloaders (even external 8Mhz clock), and still...
Always the same error (sck period while bootloader and not in sync from avrdude) - even though each time the IDE says all went fine.

I checked connections twice, can you help me out with this? I am desperate at this point. My old (first) program with blinking LED is on ATmega and I cannot upload anything else.

- can someone give me valid boards.txt file to properly configure and burn bootloader?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why do you need a bootloader if you're using ISP? But now you need to strap a crystal to the chip.

Comment: Well, don't I? Can I directly upload sketches through USBasp without bootloader? I thought it's a must-have, I dunno. I adde a crystal to chip, no positive results.

Comment: Did you set any fuse bit for external clock?

Comment: @winny: Most certainly, if the bootloader was uploaded via the IDE.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's usually how I loose communication and have to dig up a crystal somewhere.

Comment: At your level of expertise, I'd suggest to flash stuff via UART using the bootloader. It's hard to break anything that way.

Comment: I connected ATmega once again and now the IDE only says "target doesnt anwer". I killed it, right? Nevertheless, can you somehow tell me what I did wrong? My first program uploaded just right, but at that point it was over to do anything else

Comment: Nevermind, I added crystal and my LED keeps blinking. BUT STILL. No way I can upload new program. The old one took over. Any ideas? avrdude says (via verbose) that nnothing was sent, nothing received, not in sync, duh...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I solved it out. I feel really dumb but I gotta say what I did for other dummies with the same issue :)

I added the quartz and burnt another bootloader (eventually it was duemilanove 328) and then I just did File > Upload using programmator (im not sure of the english translation) and it worked... I didn't even know there is diffrence between upload button and this.

Comment: Upload = upload sketch to pre-existing bootloader using UART(FTDI, PL2303, CH340, etc). Upload using programmer = burn bootloader + sketch using ISP (USBAsp, Arduino as ISP, Atmel ICE, etc)